# golang the efficient way/lib to get a key from json string,and use this key to do geoip,then add geoip info to json

Tags: json, go, syslog

just as title,I want to use golang to do geoip,the msg is json format like below

> {"type":"big_platform","xrealip":"8.8.8.8","scheme":"http","log_time":"24/Feb/2017:15:36:10 +0800","http_method":"GET","hostname":"XXX.com","url":"/v126330.apk","http_code":"206","send_byte":20972063,"user_agent":"63(android;KOOMII-K8;6.0;480x854;WIFI;1118.24)","@timestamp":"2017-02-24T15:36:10+08:00","process_time":59463,"cache_status":"TCP_HIT","refer":"-"}

I want use Go to parse this message and get xrealip,use xrealip to do geoip.then apped geoip info to this msg.

now I do it like blew

```
//parse json string ,add geoip info and return new msg
func geoInfoAdd(msg string) ([]byte, error) {
        data := make(map[string]interface{})
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg), &data)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        //type assert value
        var ok bool
        if ipValue, ok = data[ipKey].(string); !ok {
                // ask_price is not a string
                return nil, errors.New("ipvalue not string")
        }

        //get ip location
        loc, err := ip17mon.Find(ipValue)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        iplocation := map[string]string{"country": loc.Country, "region": loc.Region, "isp": loc.Isp}

        //newdata := data
        data["iplocation"] = iplocation
        newmsg, err := json.Marshal(data)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        return newmsg, nil
}
```

but thats realy slow,cost lots of cpu,i need to do this action like 70000/second. and i really need better way to do this.

thanks

Comment: use a  struct instead of map[string]interface{},  for json.marshal/unmarshal, about twice quicker on my test.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly need just the xrealip from this json, just do the work you need by hand. This is probably a lot faster (you'd need to benchmark), as Adam said below your time on the network might be more significant than time spent parsing this json:

```
// Find the key
key := `xrealip":"`
i := strings.Index(data,key) + len(key)
if i == -1 {
  return errors.New("no ip")
}

// Extract ip up to max ip len (IPV4)
ip := data[i:i+15]

// Cut to just ip 
q := strings.Index(ip,`"`)
if q > -1 {
  ip = ip[:q]
}
```

Your functions should probably work with bytes, not strings, and scan through rather than cutting by finding " but the above is based on your function.

There are other json packages (https://github.com/pquerna/ffjson), but the main problem is processing all this data when you only want one key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured the json serialization to show it's the problem?
Alternatives could be;

- write a straight string parser
- use custom struct with `json:"arg_name"`

However I'd expect most of you time to be here;

```
loc, err := ip17mon.Find(ipValue)
```

Given you are using go, goroutines and channels would be an obvious first step to improve throughput performance for me.

1. push each new ip to process to a ipChannel
2. read from ipChannel in 'lookup' goroutine do lookup and process result
3. use error channel for things that go wrong

have as many 'lookup' channels as you need.